# How can I import Rpool

Tags: command-line, 22.04, initramfs, 22.10

Gave up waiting for suspend/resume service
Aborted
Error: 134

Failed to import pool 'rpool'
Manualny import the pool and exit

BusyBox v1.35.0
I can't post image here because its over 2 MB

Comment: Duplicate ? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1425081/failed-to-import-pool-rpool-after-zeroing-nvram

Comment: Zpool doesn't work